# Dbt macro that consumes too many execution resources

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

I made a dbt macro which runs automatically at the end of the test execution :

```
{% macro tests_results_logs(results) %}

  {%- set test_results = [] -%}
    {%- for result in results -%}
      {%- if result.node.resource_type == 'test' and result.status != 'skipped' -%}
        {%- do test_results.append(result) -%}
      {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}

  {%- set tests_results_logs_table = target.schema ~ '.dbt_tests_logs_2' -%}
  {%- set article_number_query = run_query('SELECT article_number FROM bigqueryproject.dataset.table.test_article_number LIMIT 100') -%}

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dataset2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'dbt_tests_logs_2')
  THEN
    CREATE TABLE {{ tests_results_logs_table }} (
      article_number STRING,
      test_name STRING,
      test_status STRING,
      computed_on_timestamp TIMESTAMP
    );
  END IF;

  DELETE FROM {{ tests_results_logs_table }} WHERE 1=1;

  {%- for result in test_results -%}
    {%- if execute -%}
      {%- for row in article_number_query -%}
        INSERT INTO {{ tests_results_logs_table }} VALUES (
          "{{ row.article_number }}",
          "{{ result.node.name }}",
          "{{ result.status }}",
          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
        );
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}

{% endmacro %}
```

However, once all the tests have been executed, the dbt_tests_logs_2 table begins to fill with data then the terminal very quickly displays

```
The query is too large. The maximum standard SQL query length is 1024.00K characters, including comments and white space characters.
```

It seem that INSERT in a loop is not a good way to do it.
How can I modify my macro so that it consumes less resources while keeping the main logic of the program ?